# "new project wizard" source code in eclipse to be implemented as a part of plugin

Tags: eclipse

How can I find the eclipse source code for "New project wizard" creation.I want the source code where eclipse implements the tree structure to add various project types like C/C++,android,Java etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is available at org.eclipse.ui.workbench.

Class is NewWizard.java.

If you want your contribution to come in the New Wizard UI.You should implement org.eclipse.ui.newWizard extension point.

cheers,
Saurav

Comment: The Eclipse RCP workbench contains source jar files in the plugins directory.  One of those source jar files is org.eclipse.ui.workbench.