# Standard Menu does not appear on eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, menu, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am writing an Eclipse plugin for which I want to re-use the File > New... menu leading to the wizard to include my start menu's. For this, I have the following simple code:

```xml
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            allPopups="false"
            locationURI="menu:file">
            <menu label="New">
                <command
                      commandId="org.eclipse.ui.file.newQuickMenu">
                </command>
            </menu>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>
```

My expectation is that I should see File > New... But no such menu appears. What am I missing?

Comment: Do want your contribution to come in the File ->New Wizard UI ?

Comment: @saurav I have a wizard which I want to start as part of Fine > New... Just like you have File > New... > Class , etc.

Comment: You could have a look at this Stackoverflow entry 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17738396/new-project-wizard-source-code-in-eclipse-to-be-implemented-as-a-part-of-plugi/17738758#17738758

Comment: @saurav I already have the newWizard extension point. I have associated my wizard to it. But now I want to associate it to the File menu. Problem is, my File menu does not show up at all when I start up my plugin.

Comment: You dont need to do anything. The wizard will automatically come under File->New->Other

Comment: But I do not see any menu for my plugin at all. Is there a runtime dependency I might be missing due to which I do not see the File menu?